# MVC5 Webgrid issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, webgrid

Here is my issue.  On my page I am using several webgrids pulling from various tables in the database.  I am having an issue get the column with the data to display.  If I comment out that column, the grid will display and have to correct amount of pages for the amount of data in that table.  If I put that column back in, I get the name of that column does not exist.  This is happening for all the grids.  So here is the setup of the code:

On the Controller page:

```
var cdb = new CommonModel();
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> _for = cdb.Formats
        .OrderBy(f => f.FormatName)
        .Select(f => new SelectListItem { Value = f.FormatID.ToString(), Text = f.FormatName });
ViewBag.Forma = _for;
```

On the view page:

```
@model HomeInventory.Web.Areas.Classes.Video
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add Movies / Television Shows";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MovieLayout.cshtml";
}
@{
var fgrid = new WebGrid(source: ViewBag.Forma,
                        defaultSort: "FormatName",
                        rowsPerPage: 3, canSort: false,
                        pageFieldName: "pg");


}
@fgrid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "grid", columns: fgrid.Columns(fgrid.Column(format: (Formats) => Html.CheckBox("FormatID")), fgrid.Column("FormatName")))
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Formats, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

If I run the page, I get the following error:
Column "FormatName" does not exist.  The table has it listed as FormatName, but I have also tried Format, Formats, and Name with the same result that the column does not exist.  It is quite possible I do not have something set up correctly, causing this issue.  Does anyone see what I may have missed?

Answer (score 0):

You've used LINQ to select your rows into a collection of `SelectListItem` objects, so **no**, there would not be a `FormatName` column. Your choices would be (from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem_properties%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

- Disabled
- Group
- Selected
- Text
- Value

If you want to use the columns from your table, don't use `SelectListItem`.